# How to get the array using a dynamic key in *ngFor : Angular 2+

Tags: html, angular

This is my object:

```
dynamicData = 
    {
       uni_id:{options: [1,2,3,4]},
    }
```

I want to use ngfor loop like this:

`<option *ngFor="let opt of dynamicData.uni_id.options" value="{{opt.value}}">{{ opt.label }}</option>`

The problem is : uni_id is dynamic and is available at run time. uni_id key itself is dynamic. it can be uni_id5, uni_id7 anything coming from db
How can i use it in the template

Comment: Where is label  in the json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `keyvalue` pipe to dynamically loop through object properties.

Try like this:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let opt of dynamicData | keyvalue">
    <option  *ngFor=" let item of dynamicData[opt.key].options" value="{{item}}">{{item }}</option>
  </ng-container>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qra8wm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: You are welcome, please mark the answer as correct if this was useful.

Comment: wondering why it is dynamic, if ".options" is used? Is there a way to solve without hardcoded key?

Answer (score 1):

please use it like this

```
<option *ngFor="let opt of dynamicData.uni_id?.options" value="{{opt.value}}">{{ opt.label }}</option>
```

this way you can check if data is there in `uni_id` then only show

if you are getting dynamic value for uni_id then

in ts file

```
let uniqueId = Object.keys(this.dynamicData).filter(key => key.startsWith('uni_id'))[0]
list = this.dynamicData.uniqueId
```

in html file

```
 <option *ngFor="let opt of list.options" value="{{opt.value}}">{{ opt.label }}</option>
```

Comment: uni_id key itself is dynamic. it can be uni_id5, uni_id7 anything coming from db

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable which will contain name of key:

```
keyName ='uni_id';
dynamicData = {
    uni_id: { options: [1, 2, 3, 4] }
};
```

and use this key in HTML template:

```
<select>
    <option  
       *ngFor=" let item of dynamicData[keyName].options" 
        value="{{item}}">
      {{item }}
    </option>
</select>
```

[It could be seen in stackblitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ft4nm1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)